# Python: How to separate out noise from human speech in audio file?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, signal-processing, librosa

I have an audio file in which I attempted to filter out the noise:

```
frequency, array = read('sample/OSR_us_000_0014_8k.wav')
b, a = signal.butter(5, 1000/(frequency/2), btype='highpass')
filteredSignal = signal.lfilter(b, a, newSound)
```

This highpass filter doesn't appear to be that effective though. Are there better ways to accomplish what I am attempting to do? Additionally, I would prefer to have the extracted background noise. Most algorithms available filter out the noise, but I'd like to extract the noise out as a numpy array.

Comment: This kind of thing is called *source separation*, which used to be solved with [NMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization), but is usually solved with neural networks these days. A state-of-the-art open source implementation for music can be found at [UMX](https://sigsep.github.io/open-unmix/). I would suspect something similar is out there for speech.

Comment: Can you post your sample data somewhere and provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Librosa has a function for vocal separation. Not sure if it can work with a recording with some background audio though.

https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_vocal_separation.html